# Python pandas: read csv with multiple tables repeated preamble

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Is there a pythonic way to figure out which rows in a CSV file contain headers and values and which rows contain trash and then get the headers/values rows into data frames?

I'm relatively new to python and have been using it to read multiple CSVs exported from a scientific instrument's datalog, and when dealing with CSVs so far for other tasks I've always defaulted to using the `pandas` library. However, these CSV exports can vary depending on the number of "tests" logged on each instrument.

The column headers and data structure are the same between instruments, but there is a "preamble" separating each test that can change. So I end up with backups that look something like this (for this example there are two tests, but there could be potentially any number of tests):

```
blah blah here's a test and  
here's some information  
you don't care about  
even a little bit  
header1, header2, header3  
1, 2, 3  
4, 5, 6  

oh you have another test  
here's some more garbage  
that's different than the last one  
this should make  
life interesting  
header1, header2, header3  
7, 8, 9  
10, 11, 12  
13, 14, 15
```

If it was a fixed length preamble each time I'd just use the skiprow parameter, but the preamble is variable length and the number of rows in each test is of variable length.

My end goal is to be able to merge all the tests and end up with something like:

```
header1, header2, header3  
1, 2, 3  
4, 5, 6  
7, 8, 9  
10, 11, 12  
13, 14, 15
```

Which I can then manipulate with pandas as usual.

I've tried the following to find the first row with my expected headers:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

with open('my_file.csv', 'rb') as input_file:    
    for row_num, row in enumerate(csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=',')):
        # The CSV module will return a blank list []
        # so added the len(row)>0 so it doesn't error out
        # later when searching for a string
        if len(row) > 0:
            # There's probably a better way to find it, but I just convert
            # the list to a string then search for the expected header
            if "['header1', 'header2', 'header3']" in str(row):
                header_row = row_num

    df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv', skiprows = header_row, header=0)
    print df
```

This works if I only have one test because it finds the first row that has the headers, but of course the `header_row` variable is getting updated each additional time it finds the header, so in the example above I end up with output:

```
   header1   header2   header3  
0        7         8           9
1       10        11          12
2       13        14          15
```

I'm getting lost figuring out how to append each instance of the header/dataset to a dataframe before continuing on to searching for the next instance of the header/dataset.

And it's probably not super efficient when dealing with a large number of files to have to open it once with the `csv` module then again with `pandas`.

Comment: How do you know what is a header and what is preamble? If comma's start occurring in the preamble, then you are lost...

Comment: Well the headers are at least standard in name throughout, so you know the headers are on whatever row contains 'header1, header2, header3' and the actual dataset is the rows immediately following the header row. The question is how to "slice" out the rows that have header/data and get it into a dataframe and ignore the rest.

Comment: Agreed with Chiel that commas in the preamble are the risk - if you know that you aren't going to have the same number of commas in any row in the preamble that you have in your data, using len(row) to filter them out is straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This program might help. It is essentially a wrapper around the `csv.reader()` object, which wrapper greps the good data out.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import sys


def ignore_comments(fp, start_fn, end_fn, keep_initial):
    state = 'keep' if keep_initial else 'start'
    for line in fp:
        if state == 'start' and start_fn(line):
            state = 'keep'
            yield line
        elif state == 'keep':
            if end_fn(line):
                state = 'drop'
            else:
                yield line
        elif state == 'drop':
            if start_fn(line):
                state = 'keep'

if __name__ == "__main__":

    df = open('x.in')
    df = csv.reader(df, skipinitialspace=True)
    df = ignore_comments(
        df,
        lambda x: x == ['header1', 'header2', 'header3'],
        lambda x: x == [],
        False)

    df = pd.read_csv(df, engine='python')
    print df
```

Comment: Thanks, Rob! I think this solves the problem, but I'm curious... is setting the "engine" parameter necessary in the line `df = pd.read_csv(df, engine='python')`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a more pythonic way to do that based on Pandas, (this is a quick demonstration to answer the question)

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

#define an example to showcase the solution
st = """blah blah here's a test and
here's some information  
you don't care about  
even a little bit  
header1, header2, header3  
1, 2, 3  
4, 5, 6  

oh you have another test  
here's some more garbage  
that's different than the last one  
this should make  
life interesting  
header1, header2, header3  
7, 8, 9  
10, 11, 12  
13, 14, 15""" 

# 1- read the data with pd.read_csv  
# 2- specify that you want to drop bad lines, error_bad_lines=False 
# 3- The header has to be the first row of the file. Since this is not the case, let's manually define it with names=[...] and header=None.    
data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(st), delimiter=",", names=["header1","header2", "header3"], error_bad_lines=False, header=None) 

# the trash will be loaded as follows 
# blah blah here's a test and       NaN         NaN
# let's drop these rows 
data = data.dropna()

# remove the rows which contain "header1","header2", "header3"
mask = data["header1"].str.contains('header*')
data = data[~mask]
print data
```

Now your dataFrame looks like this:

```
   header1 header2 header3
5        1       2     3  
6        4       5     6  
13       7       8     9  
14      10      11    12  
15      13      14      15
```

Comment: Thanks MedAli. This may be another Python beginner question, but what does the "~" do for you in `data = data[~mask]`? I'm having trouble finding documentation about it.

Comment: "~" means to negate the values within mask (which is an np.Series holding Boolean such as  (false, true, false, false..).

Comment: @TheJ, I hope this answered your question, if it did, please consider accepting the answer (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)