# Parsing CSV headers

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, dictionary

My requirement is to read multiple CSV files that have the data I'm interested in after `n` number of rows. This number `n` is not constant, as it varies with different CSVs (hence, I cannot use skiprows).

The format of the CSV is as follows :

```
 Test: Rate1, "2" , units
 specimen: Rectangular, "3", units

Time, Estimate, Load
(s) , (units) , (N)
"1","2","4"
"5","8","12"
```

Another CSV would probably be :

```
 Test: Rate1, "2" , units
 specimen: Rectangular, "3" , units
 value_based : Sample7, "9" , product
 Test_condition: controlled, "0" , test


Time, Estimate, Load
(s) , (units) , (N)
"12","6","8"
"18","3","2"
```

But, the only column names I'm interested in are : [`Time`, `Estimate` , `Load`].

I want to do the following:

1. Derive data with specifying headers to be `Time`, `Estimate` and `Load`.
2. Skip the first row of values ( `(s) , (units), (N)` ) as I want to concatenate these with the headers and rename them to be 
   `Time(s) , Estimate(units), Load(N)`.

This is what I have tried:

```
with open(file,"r+",newline="") as csvFile:
    dictReader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    for row in dictReader:
        print(row["Time"], row["Load"], row["Extension"])
```

```
df = pd.read_csv(file,usecols=["Time","Load","Extension"])
print(df["Time"].head(3))
```

Please suggest how I would need to proceed to be getting the data with my intended headers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503074/python-pandas-read-csv-with-multiple-tables-repeated-preamble

Comment: Thanks @D_Serg. That addresses a part of my question through a utility function. I'm just still wondering if what I want could be achieved through, may be,  another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Pandas itself is able to determine the correct starting row, but it could be done with a little preparsing of the file to determine the correct row. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

filename = 'test.csv'
header_row = ["Time", "Estimate", "Load"]

with open(filename, newline='') as f_csv:
    for row_number, row in enumerate(csv.reader(f_csv), start=-1):
        if row == header_row:
            break

df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=row_number, names=header_row)
print(df)
```

Giving:

```
   Time  Estimate  Load
0     1         2     4
1     5         8    12
```

Comment: Thank you. Coincidentally, I thought of this method after I posted the question, implemented it and it solved my problem. This is the right method.